# How to properly maintain data for Testcontainers in init script?

Tags: java, spring, docker, integration-testing, testcontainers

I am using Testcontainers to load a Dockerized database to be used for my Spring Boot application for integration testing. I currently an using an initialization script to load all of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.table1 (
...
...
);

CREATE TABLE public.table2 (
...
...
);
```

This is all working fine. I also have my own manual test data that I insert to test different scenarios:

```
-- Data for pre-existing quiz
INSERT INTO public.table1 (id, prop1, prop2) values (1, 'a', 'b');
INSERT INTO public.table2 (id, prop1, prop2) values (1, 'c', 'd');
INSERT INTO public.table2 (id, prop1, prop2) values (2, 'e', 'f');
```

Again, this is all working fine, and I am using a YAML file to read mock these objects to be used for my tests

```
  table1s:
    first:
      id: 1
      prop1: a
      prop2: b
  table2s:
    first:
      id: 1
      prop1: c
      prop2: d
    second:
      id: 2
      prop1: e
      prop2: f
```

In which I will be able to put these into a class that I can read from the YAML file properties so it can be used for my test classes

```
public class Table1TestData {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private UUID id;
    private boolean prop1;
    private boolean prop2;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean getProp1() {
        return prop1;
    }

    public void setProp1(String trial) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }

    ....

    public Table1TestData getFirstRowData(){
        Table1HelperFactory ret = new Table1HelperFactory();
        ret.setId(UUID.fromString(env.getProperty("table1s.first.id")));
        ret.setProp1(env.getProperty("table1s.first.id"));
        ....
        return ret;
    }
    ....

}
```

And I use this helper as an autowired entity in my tests (especially for my Service classes):

```
public class Table1ServiceTest {

  @ClassRule
  public static PostgresContainer postgresContainer = PostgresContainer.getInstance();


  @Autowired
  Table1Service table1Service;

  @Autowired
  Table1TestData table1TestData;

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @BeforeAll
  private static void startup() {
    postgresContainer.start();
  }


  @Test
  @DisplayName("Table 1 Service Test")
  @Transactional
  public void findTable1ById() throws Exception {
    Table1TestData testData = table1TestData.getFirstRowData();
    Table1 table1 = table1Service.findTable1ById(testData.getId());
    assertNotNull(table1);
    assertEquals(table1.getId(), testData.getId());
    assertEquals(table1.prop1(), testData.prop1());
    ....

  }

}
```

However, let's say I have to apply a new column to Table1 (or any table really) and I put the new schema into the init script. I now have to manually go to each of these insert statements and put in a new column with a value (assuming there's no default), or even say if a column is removed (even if it doesn't affect the classes necessarily). This ends up being cumbersome.

So my question really is, for someone who is using an init script to populate test data for a containerized DB, what is the best way to go about maintaining this data efficiently without much manual curating?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take advantage of the initialization script feature for postgresql: Just place your sql scripts under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (creating the directory if necessary) and it will execute them directly without any programmatic work.

You can check out an example here:
https://github.com/gmunozfe/clustered-ejb-timers-kie-server/blob/master/src/test/java/org/kie/samples/integration/ClusteredEJBTimerSystemTest.java

Define your postgresql pointing to that directory:

```
.withFileSystemBind("etc/postgresql", "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d",
                                                        BindMode.READ_ONLY)
```

If you want different scripts per tests, have a look a this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql